# How to assign properties or descriptors such as strings and int/doubles to an object or item?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm still very much new to learning C#. I am trying to create something, and I need descriptors for it. I've had some problems with this for a while and looking online has not produced any helpful results.

The ideal solution for my problem would look something like this:

```
foo.name = "jar of pickles";
foo.desc = "it appears to be a jar of pickles.";
foo.numOfPickles = 10;
foo.price = 2.50;
```

As you can see, "foo", whatever I want to call it, has a name, a description, a number quantifying it and a price. I can then put foo into an array and refer to it like bar[0].name to get "jar of pickles" back in return.

However, I've not been able to accomplish this, because I'm not sure what to type "foo" as. I've tried as an object, but it just told me that "name" had no definition in an "object". I figured the above WAS me defining what .name was in that object, but it seemed to be a type issue.

So I tried using a dictionary to get this done.

```
new Dictionary<string, object>
```

And this does what I want, but casting every single time I want to reference something feels inelegant and hackish. Example, to borrow the price to put taxes on it, i'd have to call it as (double)bar[0].price or less dynamically (double)foo.price. I have many calculations that deal with numbers and maths and casting to every single one of them doesn't strike me as proper, but I could be mistaken.

My attempts at using the "dynamic" type in a dictionary have not worked, since it returns a CS1980 error. Frankly the solution to that seems very complicated and beyond my understanding. However if that's the only answer to this problem, then I would clearly have no choice. Again, I am very new to C# so I'm not sure entirely how dynamic pertains to this, if it's at all related to what I'm saying, or if its is very, very much related.

Any help with reaching a solution close to what I've outlined would be greatly appreciated by me.

Comment: Isn't unity support JavaScript? Trying to use C# as JavaScript would be painful - may as well switch early...

Comment: Hi Alexei. Thank you for your answer but this question has nothing to do with JavaScript.

Comment: Answer? I did not give one - it is just comment, like this one - answers go in answer box. (And I see that Unity3d no longer support "UnityScript" http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/UnityScript_versus_JavaScript... I guess you have to start liking strongly typed language :) )

Comment: There is nothing in this question about JavaScript. I do not know where you get this idea. The link is appreciated but not useful to me. As you say, C# is "strongly typed language", I have heard this many times but I am still unclear for what exactly that means and all of the ramifications. Are you implying that what I am asking cannot be done in C#, because it is a strongly typed language?

Comment: Some variation of what you are asking indeed can be done - you've already listed all standard approaches for what you wrote as requirement (`Dictionary`, `dynamics` either by itself if you just need duck typing or combined with `ExpandoObject` if you want to add properties)... and you rule them out... There essentially two ways you can go from here - review what you want to achieve and try to map that to C# concepts or start digging into features you've already listed (note that you will obviously not be able to add properties at run time to existing strongly typed objects... beware of that)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov JavaScript (cough, UnityScript) support was dropped [two years ago](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2017/08/11/unityscripts-long-ride-off-into-the-sunset/). Its gone. You can no longer create or import anything written in it into a modern version of the editor, it will not compile.

Comment: @Draco18s got it (see my comment above).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is C# script of this:

```
public class Foo
{  
    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    } 
    // or {get;set;}
    private int price;
    public int Price
    {
        get { return price; }
        set { price = value; }
    }
    //or {get;set;} 

    //and so on ...
}
```

and for using class in other methods:

```
  Foo foo1 = new Foo();
  foo1.Name = "test";
  foo1.Price = 3;

  Foo[] fooArray = new Foo[2];
  fooArray[0] = foo1;
```

Comment: I believe Unity has supported automatically-implemented properties for a very long time - I suggest you edit your example to use them, as it will massively reduce the size of the code. (Likewise I'd suggest using an object initializer in the second snippet.)

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. This is very helpful, and it works. I am having a small issue however. fooArray[0].name returns the name as desired. foo1.name returns a nullreference exception. on further inspection, this is because just foo1 returns "Null" while fooArray[0] returns "Foo". is there any reason why this happens?

Comment: Please post your code for checking. Maybe your are using foo1 before making its object( new Foo() ) or it becomes null somewhere.

Comment: Never mind. The issue was that it was being written as Foo foo1 = new Foo(); and simply changing it to foo1 = new Foo(); fixed the problem entirely.